# Insert integer value into SQL Server database from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert an integer value into a SQL Server database as below when I run the program there are no any errors, but the table doesn't get updated with values. I have searched on the internet and I am doing the same can anyone help to find what I am doing wrong.

Note: I already defined "connectionString" as a string on the form class

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int totalincome=600;
        int totaldeductions = 10;

        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BudgetApp.Properties.Settings.MainDataBaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Totals(TotalIncome, TotalDeductions) VALUES (@TotalIncome, @TotalDeductions)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalIncome", totalincome);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalDeductions", totaldeductions);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Done !!");
}
```

Comment: are you able to see the Message `Done !!` at the end of execution?

Comment: yes    Done !! Message appeared

Comment: Any chance there's a `TransactionScope` in play?

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns the number of rows affected.  If it's greater than zero, it worked.  If the database doens't show it, you are looking in the wrong database.

Comment: What does your connection string look like??

Comment: <connectionStrings>
        <add name="BudgetApp.Properties.Settings.MainDataBaseConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MainDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: probably your Windows account does not have the right privileges to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The whole *AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `MainDataBase`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MainDataBase;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Comment: Sql Server Express is kind of overkill, though, if he just wants a local datastore for a traditional desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

Code Seems correct,Perhaps you are checking the wrong DB?. I would add a Try/catch for exceptions. And remember to close connection after executing query. Regards

Answer (score 0):

check your database column datatype,use try catch.

and try to replace `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalIncome", totalincome);` to `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = totalincome;`

```
try
{
       int totalincome=600;
        int totaldeductions = 10;
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BudgetApp.Properties.Settings.MainDataBaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Totals(TotalIncome, TotalDeductions) VALUES (@TotalIncome, @TotalDeductions)", con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = totalincome;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Number", SqlDbType.Int).Value = totaldeductions;
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalIncome", totalincome);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalDeductions", totaldeductions);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```